# Running Program in Windows When Not Connected to Specific Network

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, windows-task-scheduler, event-viewer

I have a Windows 10 PC and a VPN client which does not have a trusted networks feature. I would like to automatically run the client when not connected to my office corporate network or guest WiFi network, and stop the client when

I have read that you can trigger programs in Task Scheduler to execute on Event ID 10000 which is connecting to a network, or ID 10001 when disconnecting from a network. However, I checked my Event Viewer and cannot see these events. The Task Scheduler also does not have an option under the Conditions tab to run the executable when NOT connected to a specific network.

Is there an alternative solution? There must be a simple script for this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: EventID without a source is just a number which tells nothing. Are you referring to https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/trigger-launch-program-script-connecting-to-specific-network/, perhaps? If you don't see these events at all, are you sure you're looking at the correct logfile in the first place?

Comment: @Peregrino69 I was checking System, Administrative and Application logs. There are ID 10000 events but no NetworkProfile events. Yes, I was referring to that post.

Comment: Yap, wrong log. The article does specify NetworkProfile/Operational. In Event viewer look under Applications and Services Logs -> Microsoft -> Windows - that's where you'll find the folder NetworkProfile, in which you'll find Operational -logfile. Which I can confirm does show 10000 as "Network Connected". I've not been pulling your leg; I never even knew about that log until just now - I even missed it when I skimmed the article yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Triggering scripts / programs based on the Network Connect -events is described in https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/trigger-launch-program-script-connecting-to-specific-network/. These events are logged in

```
Event Viewer
   \-> Applications and Services Logs
             \-> Microsoft
                     \-> Windows
                            \-> NetworkProfile
                                       \-> Operational
```